# CSS - Make sans-serif font imitate monospace font

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a logo/home button for my webpage which is the abbreviation of my project (the temp letters I use are ABCDEF). I am using Arial for the font (although may change it later). As you can see from the photo of the logo, the letters do not completely align under each other.

[image]

I've tried `font-kerning: none;` which helps but does not completely make it do what I want it to do.

I've made a jsfiddle for this example and here's the link: https://jsfiddle.net/7dfetxto/

Otherwise, here's my code (same as in the jsfiddle):

**HTML**

```
<div id="logo">
  <a href="#">
    <h1>ABC</br>DEF</h1>
  </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#logo{
  font-family: "arial", "times", "sans-serif";
  width: 128px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #336699;
  float: left;
}
#logo a{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#logo h1{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 26px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-kerning: none;
  display: block;
  color: white;
}
```

**My goal is to get the letters on the second line to fall directly under their respective letter on the first line.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## letter-spacing

Use CSS `letter-spacing` property.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7dfetxto/5/).

[image: screenshot]

```css
#logo {
  font-family: "arial", "times", "sans-serif";
  width: 128px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #336699;
  float: left;
}
#logo a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#logo h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 26px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-kerning: none;
  display: block;
  color: white;
}
.h1b {
  letter-spacing: 3.25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <a href="#">
    <h1>ABC<br><span class="h1b">DEF</span></h1>
  </a>
</div>
```

> You might find this interesting: [kerningjs](http://kerningjs.com/)

There are more possible ways. One is

## font-size

By making the `font-size` of the second line (in this case) bigger, it will grow and reach the two sides of the first line: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7dfetxto/6/).

Comment: thanks. and thanks on the kerningjs. Now I just have to learn typography before I do that! :D