# Matching letter spacing and wrapping for different fonts with CSS on hover effect

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, hover, typesetting

I'm facing a peculiar issue with CSS and font styling that I hope to get some insights on. I have implemented an effect where the font of a text element changes on hover. The challenge is that when the font changes, the new font has different letter spacing and wrapping, causing it to sometimes wrap to a new line. This change in wrapping results in the font no longer being hovered over, which causes a glitch where it reverts back to the original font.

Here's a basic outline of what I'm trying to achieve:

Text is displayed in Font A.
On hover, the text changes to Font B.
The spacing and wrapping of Font B should match that of Font A, preventing the text from shifting or wrapping to a new line.
I've considered adjusting the tracking (letter-spacing) of the fonts to make them more closely match, but I'm unsure about the reliability and cross-browser compatibility of this approach.

Questions:

Is there a CSS-only solution to ensure that different fonts have matching letter spacing and wrapping behavior?
Would it be more effective to use a JavaScript package that programmatically converts each word to the new font while honoring the original line breaks and spacing? If so, any recommendations for such a package?
Here's a snippet of my current CSS for reference:

```
.my-text {
  font-family: 'Font A';
}

.my-text:hover {
  font-family: 'Font B';
}
```

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since shapes, metrics and kerning of fonts can be quite different you can't do this automatically. You could use a font editor to apply/copy the metrics from one font to another. But the result would most likely be very ugly. The closest thing you could get is to use 2 monospaced fonts and adjust letter-spacing and word-spacing properties until both fonts will produce the same line-lengths and line wraps

Comment: For a more stylized design approach (e.g "scrabble "like letters) You might adapt [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73787166/how-to-imitate-a-monospace-font-with-a-variable-width-font/73822001#73822001) wrapping each letter in a span with a fixed width. Using variable fonts with a width axis can also help to normalize both text renderings.

Comment: Wow, thanks for these suggestions. I like the approach you mention in the second comment. Would wrapping each letter in a span with a fixed width honour the line breaks between each font?

Comment: Should work, provided you give each span an inline-block display property and the same width - see the linked examples snippet (I've tested something similar , just scroll scroll down to the last examples).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I will explore this option and will report back. If a font is monospaced, does this mean each letter takes up the same width? Or that there are no overlap between letters?  Thanks for clarifying

Comment: Yes in a monospaced font each glyph has the sam width. But different monospace fonts have different width. However you could bring them to a common width tweaking tracking and word spaces